# Java - Can enum in a parameter of an abstract method

Tags: java, enums, abstract-class, subclass

I am not familiar with enum and want to ask whether I can put a enum in an abstract method and override it in other class? 
Here is an example I am working with:

I have many subclasses that extend the abstract class, they each have their own sub command as an enum type. The enum type has a int ID and String name.

Also, a method takes the sub command and change the input UI base on the selected sub command.

```
public class CommandOne extends CommandClass{
    ........

    public void updateUIBySubCmd(SubCommand subCmd){
          /*Do Something*/
    }

    private enum SubCommand{
        SubCmd1    (ID1, Name1),
        SubCmd2    (ID2, Name2),
        ........
    }
}
```

I have an abstract class that is extended by the above subclass, it does not consist any enum but only a couple function that override by the subclass.

The question is, can I do the following and have the method updateUIBySubCmd become abstract with an enum type? If it is allowed, how do I accomplish it?

```
public abstract class CommandClass{
..........
    public abstract void updateUIBySubCmd(Enum x);
}
```

Comment: You have the code, why not try it?

Comment: Because it gives me the error:
method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Comment: if the enums implement a common interface, you can do this.

Comment: Try using `Enum<?>` or `Class<? extends Enum<?>>` as the type in your abstract declaration

Comment: There's no need to put the `SubCommand` enum inside the `CommandOne` class.  Make it a top-level declaration in its own file.  You haven't really given enough information for us to tell what you _really_ want to accomplish.  If all you want to is be able to pass `SubCommand`s to the method, that's all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```
public abstract class CommandClass<E extends Enum<E>> {
..........
    public abstract void updateUIBySubCmd(E x);
}

public class CommandOne extends CommandClass<SubCommand> {
    ........

    @Override
    public void updateUIBySubCmd(SubCommand subCmd){
          /*Do Something*/
    }
}

public enum SubCommand {
    SubCmd1    (ID1, Name1),
    SubCmd2    (ID2, Name2),
    ........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java Enums are essentially classes that extend java.lang.Enum. That's why you're getting the error that you're getting. The parent class cannot specify one type and the subclass expect a more restricted type. It has to specify Enum as well.

However, I am not sure that an ENum is really what you want here. You probably want a common interface type for a subcommand and then to specify the various commands as static nested classes in the specific command implementations. This will not, however, provide you with any compile-time type safety since you would still have the problem that the subclass takes the same interface type as the parent.